# how to stop enter character in textbox in mobile?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
    && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
```

I am using this javascript function  code for entering  only number in the text box it is working on computers but when I am opening this website in mobile I am able to enter characters in the text box using mobile any solution for this

Comment: instead of `return false` try `evt.preventDefault();` it will works

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, if you want to use to be able to enter **only** numbers on your input, you can always use input of type `tel`.

```
<input type="tel">
```

You can try running the below on your mobile device, and you will realise that the number pads (instead of the normal alphabets keyboard) will appear.

```html
<label>Enter only numbers:</label>

<input type="tel">
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution can be using pattern for your input which suppose to accept only number, you can add this to your input:

```
pattern="\d+"
```

The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against on form submission.

Note: The pattern attribute works with the following input types: text, date, search, url, tel, email, and password.